# isPaged method from Pageable object

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How to use the `isPaged()` in `Pageable` object.I have created `pageable` object like this.

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest (pageNumber,pageSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#isPaged--)

> default boolean isPaged()
>
> Returns whether the current Pageable contains pagination information.

So just do

```
if (pageable.isPaged()) {
  // use it, for example
  pageable.getPageSize();
}
```

Comment: I am unable find isPaged() method from the pageable.  I am using Spring data jpa(1.11.9) version. is there any problem???

Answer (score -1):

I have to created new answer because I cannot comment due to my reputation is below 50.

If you do some search you will see that Pageable class is in spring-data-commons.

Then you can see from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.9.RELEASE) that your spring-data-jpa 1.11.9 used spring-data-commons 1.13.9.RELEASE

After that, you need to search for Pageable.java that is in spring-data-commons repository version 1.13.x (which is in github).

And boom! you will see that in Pageable class of the spring-data-jpa you used does not contains isPaged method.

Hope this helps.